# Is an integer variable not numeric in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, variables, integer, numeric

I have `user_waiting` period saved as an integer in my `DB`. I am trying to use it in the below code, but I keep getting the error `"Expected Numeric."` I am very new to `Ruby`, and my understanding was that an integer would be numeric. Am I incorrect in this understanding?

```
 if @pto_management.waiting_period.nil?
    @pto_management.accrual_begin_date = current_user.start_date
 else
     @pto_management.accrual_begin_date = current_user.start_date + 
                             @pto_management.user_waiting_period
  end
```

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: Check if `p @pto_management.user_waiting_period` returns a number `42` or a string `"42"`. Then post the section of your `db/schema.rb` file that describes the source table; it might not be an `integer`.

Comment: I am using Postgress. When I run my ruby console, it looks like a number, no quotes around it. I am not sure if there is a better way to check.  And my db section for it 

 t.integer  "user_waiting_period"

Comment: Is "Expected Numeric." the whole error message? Are you getting an exception or a validation error or something else?

Comment: "TypeError in PtoManagementsController#create" is across the top of the error, then "Expected Numeric" is what it shows on what is causing it. It then highlights my line of code "current_user.start_date + @pto_management.user_waiting_period" If I remove @pto_management.user_waiting_period and instead put an actual number, the code works fine and does the correct calculation.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. I'd say first try `p @pto_management.user_waiting_period.inspect` - without the inspect, sometimes things are interpreted differently to print nicely, but inspect will definitely show you the difference between strings and integers. (try `put "42".inspect` vs `puts 42.inspect` so you know the difference yourself). To answer your initial question: yes integers are definitely numeric (as you've proven by trying an actual number in place of the variable), so now it's just up to us to probe what the bug is that's causing this error :)

Comment: you can also use `.class` like `puts current_user.start_date.class` and see integer or string type of yr variable

Comment: I apologize!! I figured it out! I had forgotten I had tried fiddling with some code in the model before that was converting `user_waiting_period` to a boolean. It works now.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps explicitly convert it to an int?

```
if @pto_management.waiting_period.nil?
  @pto_management.accrual_begin_date = current_user.start_date
else
  @pto_management.accrual_begin_date = current_user.start_date + 
                         @pto_management.user_waiting_period.to_i # <-- HERE
end
```

Comment: Hmmm, I now get the error of "Undefined method `to_i' for true:TrueClass Did you mean? to_s"  That doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Well then, ask yourself why your `user_waiting_period` has a boolean value